# Where should I put -cp when compiling/running java files

Tags: java

I tried

`javac Something.java -cp ".; some\\directory\\xxx.jar"`

and it worked. I could compile the file in this way.

But when running the file, i realized that I must put -cp in front, making it

`java -cp ".;some\\directory\\xxx.jar" Something`

Why is there such a difference?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, you don't need to double backslash in a value passed from CMD to Java commandline, as you do in Java source (always) in and _Unix shell_ commands (sometimes). It does no harm, though, except at the _beginning_ of a pathname, just like double slash in a Unix pathname except the beginnning has the same effect as single slash. And you don't need to double-quote this value in CMD whereas you would need to quote or escape in shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while running, anything you provide after `Something` will be treated as program argument